# How to prevent users from spamming the system with record updates back and forth?

Tags: data, administration, spam

I have struggled with the UX for this general problem for quite some time, and not sure the best way to handle it. The basic problem is, imagine a user submitting a dictionary term. Say you can customize the definition of the term, and say that users get points for making *useful* submissions/changes to the data set (so they get points for a useful update to the definition).

The *guards* I've imagined to put in place so far to this situation are:

- Don't allow users to just save the form without any changes.
- Track the changes, so we can tell if the user has made any changes to this field (recently, like in the past week?).
- Rate limit on a word-by-word basis (this is a dictionary site) so a network of bots can't just do the same thing, spread over multiple pretend users.
- Make users sign up with Facebook potentially (as they have more stringent user signup requirements).

But how to handle the situation where they just add a single character, save, remove the character, save, add a character, save, remove the character save, etc.? If you only give points for the fact that they have changed the term, then perhaps that simplifies the problem a little.

But how would you go about preventing the spamming of updates to a single term?

Comment: Unless the points are rewarded based on some algorithm (i.e. not reviewed by a person), why would spamming the entry with updates cause any issues? If you can explain the process for the rewarding of points that would help clarify the problem.